# How to export xml file in progress 4gl?

Tags: xml, progress-4gl

I'm a rookie in progress 4gl. Can any one say how to export xml format like as follows using SAX-WRITER in Progress 4GL. Here is the format;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <IoTInfo>
        <Info Name="ApplicationID" Value="IoTBuffer" />
        <Info Name="ResourceID" Value="Lansing_DO" />
        <Info Name="HostName" Value="Adient-RTA-USE-IoTHub-01.azure-devices.net" />
        <Info Name="DeviceId" Value="582-01" />
        <Info Name="PrimaryDeviceKey" Value="4n3yEihan+ikfEe1EkI0i/CNeTfiMHdzQCcUQthO4R4=" />
        <Info Name="SecondaryDeviceKey" Value="Ue7dNJvVYGRmyVIl4l91hQS0TUDCwvdLs/2X+OWUBe0=" />
        <Info Name="TransportType" Value="Mqtt_WebSocket_Only" />
        <Info Name="RetryPolicy" Value="Exponential_Backoff_With_Jitter" />
        <Info Name="OperationTimeout" Value="15000" />
        <Info Name="IoTMessage" Value="{&quot;DeviceId&quot;:&quot;469&quot;}" />
        <Info Name="MsgTimeStamp" Value="11/20/2019 1:40:12 PM" />
    </IoTInfo>
```

Comment: Every 'Info Name' block is ending with "/". I don't know how to generate it within the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the SAX-WRITER for that. You can define a simple dataset and a temp-table and output it's XML representation.

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttInfo NO-UNDO SERIALIZE-NAME "info"
    FIELD InfoName  AS CHARACTER XML-NODE-TYPE "attribute" SERIALIZE-NAME "Name"   
    FIELD InfoValue AS CHARACTER XML-NODE-TYPE "attribute" SERIALIZE-NAME "Value" .

DEFINE DATASET dsInfo SERIALIZE-NAME "IoTInfo" FOR ttInfo .  

CREATE ttInfo.
ASSIGN ttInfo.InfoName  = "ApplicationID"
       ttInfo.InfoValue = "InfoValue".

CREATE ttInfo.
ASSIGN ttInfo.InfoName  = "ResourceID"
       ttInfo.InfoValue = "Lansing_DO".

DATASET dsInfo:WRITE-XML("file", "c:\temp\xml.xml", FALSE).

DISPLAY "Done".
```